# Maven Project showing error in Visual Studio code while building package

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I have installed Maven for Java v0.41.0 though visual studio IDE.
And installed Extension Pack for Java v0.25.11

I also setup JAVA_HOME and MAVEN_HOME separately in my PC.
When I run Maven commands through command prompt every thing works fine.
But if I tried to execute any maven command through visual studio I am getting this below error

```
TOPP_TELECOM+syali@TFITGOVLT97482 MINGW64 /c/Jdk/Practice/maven_demo/my-app
$ "C:\Users\syali\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-maven-0.41.0\resources\maven-wrapper\.mvn\wrapper\maven-wrapper.jar" clean -f "c:\Jdk\Practice\maven_demo\my-app\pom.xml"
bash: C:\Users\syali\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-maven-0.41.0\resources\maven-wrapper\.mvn\wrapper\maven-wrapper.jar: cannot 
execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I tried to execute maven command from Visual Studio Code. but I am getting error

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28000794/18359438) solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

JAVA_HOME is requiered for mvn (Maven) commands to work on your system.

Verify that JAVA_HOME is configured correctly (cmd Windows): `echo %JAVA_HOME%`

To run mvn commands, you just need to add your mvnLocation/bin folder to your local PATH environment variables.

Also when updating environment variables. The terminal needs to be restarted. -> Restart VsCode

Source: https://maven.apache.org/install.html

Comment: Actually I have   JAVA_HOME & MAVEN_HOME defined in my pc  local PATH environment variables. and they are running fine. But if I run Maven  using extension it is showing this error .below is   from my vs terminal :$ echo $JAVA_HOME
C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.7.7-hotspot